# Encrypt before writing image to disk

Tags: go, encryption, aes

Given the following code:

```
import (
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/png"
    "os"
)

var img = image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 100, 100))
var col color.Color

func main() {
    col = color.RGBA{255, 0, 0, 255} // Red
    HLine(10, 20, 80)
    col = color.RGBA{0, 255, 0, 255} // Green
    Rect(10, 10, 80, 50)

    f, err := os.Create("draw.png")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    png.Encode(f, img)
}
```

How to encrypt the image with AES ***before*** it is written to the disk? Unfortunately, png.Encode() is not returning an encoded file but is directly writing the file. If it was returning a file, the approach would be clear to me. But so...I'm stucked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`png.Encode` takes an `io.Writer`, a standard Go interface, and writes into it. So it's not directly writing into a file.

**First step**: pass a `bytes.Buffer` to `png.Encode`, then you'll have the PNG image encoded as a byte slice in the buffer.

**Second step**: use the `aes` module to encrypt the byte buffer. See the example in the official docs: https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/cipher#example-NewCBCEncrypter or check out [this post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/aes-encryption-of-files-in-go/).

Comment: How much data io.Writer can handle?

Comment: `io.Writer` is an interface, it doesn't actually do anything at runtime. Types implementing it can "handle data". A `bytes.Buffer` implements `io.Writer` and is variable size - it will grow as new data gets written into it, like a slice